# No of ways in which n indistinguishable items can be placed in m indistinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This problem is the same as
number of ways to partition n into exactly m parts.

The recurrence given in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Intermediate_function) has

p(n,k) =  the number of partitions of n using only natural numbers ≥ k

How to find no of partitions of n which has exactly k non-zero parts? Is there a recurrence relation to solve this?

Comment: [Here](http://oeis.org/A026820) and [here](http://oeis.org/A008284) are relevant entries in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. Recurrence relations included.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with computer science and belongs in math.stackexchange.

Comment: @Yuval: ... where it will be closed as a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372889/number-of-partitions-of-n-with-k-parts).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Combinatorics are regularly used in algorithm analysis. If we close this one as offtopic, we'd have to close all the asymptotics questions around by the same token.

Comment: This is an elementary question. Have you done some reading? What are your thoughts? (Note that the "recurrence" you give is not really a recurrence.)

Comment: @Raphael It already has an answer on math.stackexchange, see Peter's comment.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: That does not invalidate my argument. I also don't think the question-answer pair Peter links is particularly helpful.

Comment: @Raphael I'm not convinced by your argument. Big O asymptotics is stuff you get to in an algorithms class. The type of combinatorics exemplified by the present question isn't. If there were an explicit connection to an analysis of an algorithm, then that's something else - but even in that case, we would probably only care about the asymptotics, whereas here the OP wants an exact formula.

Comment: @Raphael: The question I linked asked for a proof of the formula that the OP wants. So the answer to the OP's question is contained in the question I linked to. I don't see how it fails to be relevant.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Some algorithms classes do teach combinatorics, others don't. Some algorithms classes are interested in exact solutions, others aren't. I don't think your generalisations are valid. (It's true that this question does not seem to be immediately related to an algorithm analysis, but that is also true for a number of asymptotics questions.)

Comment: @PeterShor: I wrote "not helpful", not "irrelevant". Arguably, getting to the recurrence and understanding that step is far more important than the technical part of solving it. Note that the question you link has neither; hints can be appropriate as an answer, though.

Comment: This is really computer science part of combinatorics, lots of similar ideas (but much more complicated) like Ramsey theorem are used to show an existence of polynomial time algorithms for some problems. I think we should say welcome to (cs) combinatorics in our community, even if this has an answer in math.SE, it's better to answer it here, because here we look at it as a CS problem not math.

Comment: These comments should be on [meta] not here.

Comment: There is a [related discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-questions-about-other-sciences-for-computer-scientists-be-on-topic) but I think we have to discuss mathematics in particular. Some people hear seem to think they know exactly which part of mathematics is also computer science, and that is troublesome.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/704/98) for a new discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The number of partitions of $n$ with exactly $k$ parts is the coefficient of $x^n y^k$ in the generating series
$$ \prod_{l=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^ly}. $$
Asymptotically, this is probably $\Theta_k(n^{k-1})$ (i.e. the constant depends on $k$).

The number of partitions of $n$ in which each part is at least $k$ is
$$ \prod_{l=k}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^l}. $$
Asymptotically, my guess is that it's $\Theta_k(p(n))$, where $p(n)$ is the number of *all* partitions of $n$.

We can write a recurrence relation for $p(n,k)$: $p(0,k) = 1$ and for $n > 0$,
$$ p(n,k) = \sum_{t \leq \lfloor n/k \rfloor} p(n-kt,k+1). $$